# VS CODE Chrome Debugger не работает

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, отладка, visual-studio-code

Когда запускаю отладку HTML файла, то вне зависимости от браузера вижу такую картину.
А в Brackets или PHPStorm нормально работает отладка, мне понравился сам редактор, хотел попользоваться, эта проблема расстроила.
[image: Так это выглядит в браузере.]

Comment: Мне нужно мозги.

Comment: Браузер не может соединиться с сервером по адресу `localhost:8080` Насколько я помню, VSCode использует nodejs для запуска сервера.

Comment: Может установка виртуального сервера решит мою проблему. Что-то в духе Open Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Забыли включить сервер

```
npm start
```

Answer (score 0):

В общем решилась проблема тем что я установил дополнение Live Server, и сначала запускал сервер, ну а потом указал в настройках отладчика ссылку по которой это дело доступно, вроде работает.)
Спасибо за помощь.